# Oracle - How should I accelerate page load from Oracle table query with field values stored in a table using EAV (Entity Attribute Value) design?

Tags: oracle, performance, asynchronous, query-optimization

**Problem Summary**

I have a page on a web application in PHP when the page loads that stalls the page quite a bit on load.  Currently there is a query, that fetches records on a page, individual records for a page, that amounts to about 160 records.    When I add a query in this loop record fetch (the query underneath), each record fetch takes about 20-30 seconds on individual fetch.

**Current Configuration**

Our application does not own or host the database and it merely can query for records in the web PHP application, and we do not have access to add indices or change stored procedures, etc...

**Bottleneck Query**

```
SELECT t1.tablefield,
       t1.tableid,
       t1.fieldname as license
       t2.fieldname as state
       t3.fieldname as excluded
FROM
       tableofdata t1,
       tableofdata t2,
       tableofdata t3
WHERE
        t1.org = :location
    AND t2.org = :t1.org
    AND t1.customer = t2.customer
    AND t1.sequence = t2.sequence
    AND t1.sequence2 = t2.sequence2
    AND t3.org = t2.org
    AND t3.customer = t2.customer
    AND t1.code = 'license'
    AND t2.code = 'state'
    AND t3.code = 'status'
    AND t1.value  = :license
    AND t2.value  = :state
    AND t3.value  = 'Excluded';
```

**How do I fix this?**

***A) Optimize Query?***

1. Do I try speeding up either the query (modifying self joins / predicates, composing a long predicate condition of record values) if feasible, can speed up the page to load faster?   Right now code is not active but I have queried by individual values in a query browser and each record fetch takes ~20 seconds.*

***B) Use Asynchronous Select PHP Select Statements?***

1. Should I try to fork out asynchronous selects in PHP to produce records in the loop and join the results into a MySQL table that I do have root access to?

***C) Load data from MySQL / Synchronize with Oracle, using a Scheduled Task/Cron Job?***

1. Should I save all data from Oracle data in bulk to MySQL & run a synchronization script in a scheduled task (every 30 minutes or so)?

[image]

Comment: What indexes exist on the tables?

Comment: The indices are not directly visible,  because we fetch this from a 3rd party.   I can however run explain plan if it helps,  it returns cardinality and cost report.

Comment: As you say MySQL in the request, this seems to be about MySQL, not about Oracle. I've removed the Oracle tag. If this is about Oracle and not MySQL, change your request text and the tags.

Comment: Why the out-dated join syntax? This syntax was used in the 1980s. Explicite joins (`INNER JOIN ... ON`, etc.) made it into the SQL standard before MySQL was invented.

Comment: Thorsten, MySQL is on our end, locally, Oracle what we externally query, the query above is for Oracle

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, does inner join revision produce faster results,  I did not want to ask this question to add to my post but I had this concern too,  I mistakenly assumed Oracle "revises" the query during compilation, possibly

Comment: The table design looks horrible. Some kind of hyper generic key values? Is this really three times the same table? This would partly explain why it's so slow. But did you say, you fetch row by row and each takes 20 seconds? How do you do this? Can't you just fetch all rows in one go?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224003/discussion-between-vahe-jabagchourian-and-thorsten-kettner).

Comment: readded oracle tag, since comments clarified the query is actually being run in oracle

Comment: It might help, did you show some sample data, so we see what kid of different rows the website is supposed to retrieve from the tables.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to be very cautious of showing table structure an sample data, for practical concerns, but it appears the generic key value and 3x self join is a huge cause for the query performance, that is why I wanted to reduce latency with some tricks like copying data to another db and keeping data in sync in a regular interval.

Comment: This question seems to be a possible answer to the question "Why not use EAV?"

Comment: I totally forgot EAV, and couldn't find the acronym until you used it now.  I remember this now from past research.  Thank you @spencer7593

Comment: Is ` AND t2.location = :t1.org` a typo? It often helps to put yourself in the optimizer's position. How would you, as a human, do the work required to get the result of that query? Where would you start, how much data do you think you'd need to read to do that / how much effort do you think it would take? I see 3 possible starting points - finding all the rows in the table that match either of your code, value, location combinations - which of those is going to find the least amount of rows, how many is that? Is there an index that could be used?

Comment: As to sample data and table structures: You certainly overestimate what you are about to expose. The structure looks so terrible that probably nobody would ever want to copy it :-) And as to its data: If this is a table about weapons, then show a table of toys. We don't care about the real content. We want to get an idea of the relations. Get creative.

Comment: If I have understood this correctly from our chat, this is about fetching data with one query for one row each. Yes? How many rows does the query you are showing return? Is this just one query for one row? If so, what does the query for the second row look like?

Comment: It is a query for arbitrary desired rows,  for now it is one row, because of predicate conditions I used.  However, I will need to revise to query in bulk for all predicate values, as suggested.   I will try to put out a sample safe version of the data I am retrieving.  The EAV signature of data of the table is still unknown to me still because of many types of entities stored there.   And to the point of no one wanting to copy it,  I agree.  ;)

Comment: EAV = Entitry, Attribute, Value.  It is probably the worst design concept ever foisted on the rdbms world.  I often cite this article, and can only echo the words of one of the participants:  "Run Like Hell".

Comment: The emphasize is on the **RDBMS** @EdStevens it runs *fine* elsewhere ;)

Comment: @MarmiteBomber - well, oracle _is_ an rdbms.  And the issues detailed by the author of the cited article are fundamental with the design, not unique to how the oracle architecture handles it.

Comment: What details should I add to reopen question?  I seemed to successfully implement proposed method before recognizing the problem might have been my specific query an location in a loop.  Moving my query outside of the loop and populating an associative array accelerated the page fetch by a noticeable performance, almost, if not as fast as original.